# Is there a selector for the next and prev buttons?

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to select the next and prev buttons on the month view calendar to hide a dialog box when switching months.

Something like:

```
$(selector for buttons).live('click',function(){$("#dialog_frame").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

I can't find a selector for the buttons.  Is there one or is there a way to create one?

Thanks for any help.

Cheers

Comment: What language/platform is this for? You won't get much visibility with just the fullcalendar tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went on the site and right clicked over one of the buttons to inspect the element using Chrome Dev tools.The buttons:`<span class="fc-button"> &nbsp;►&nbsp;</span>`
There's your selector.

Comment: Yup.  That was it.  Thanks so much.